# I have configured my uwsgi.ini file and its working fine with nohup. How can auto start uwsgi on boot?

Tags: django, nginx, amazon-ec2, uwsgi

Here is my uesgi.conf code

```
description "uWSGI"
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [06]
respawn

env UWSGI=/usr/local/bin/uwsgi
env LOGTO=/var/log/uwsgi.log

exec $UWSGI --master --emperor /home/ubuntu/socialtalks/config --die-on-term --uid socialtalks --gid www-data --logto $LOGTO
```

Here is the ini file configuration.

uwsgi.ini

```
    [uwsgi]
# variables
#projectname = thesocialtalks
#base = /home/ubuntu/thesocialtalks

# configuration
#master = true
env = /home/ubuntu/socialtalks
#pythonpath = %(base)
#chdir = %(base)
env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=%(projectname).settings.production
#module = thesocialtalks.wsgi:application
#socket = /tmp/%(projectname).sock

# mysite_uwsgi.ini file
[uwsgi]
projectname = socialtalks
pcre = true
base = /home/ubuntu/socialtalks
# Django-related settings
# the base directory (full path)
#chdir           = /home/ubuntu/socialtalks
chdir = %(base)
# Django's wsgi file
#module          = socialtalks.wsgi
module           = %(projectname).wsgi
# the virtualenv (full path)
#home            = /home/admin5/test/thesocialtalks_final/thesocialtalks
plugin = python37
# process-related settings
# master
master          = true
enable-threads = true

# maximum number of worker processes
processes       = 10
# the socket (use the full path to be safe
#socket          = /home/ubuntu/socialtalks/mysite.sock
socket = /tmp/%(projectname).sock
# ... with appropriate permissions - may be needed
chmod-socket = 666
uid = www-data
gid = www-data

# clear environment on exit
vacuum          = true
```

I am running the script using the command

```
nohup uwsgi --ini config/uwsgi.ini &
```

How to automate my uwsgi to auto start after system boot?

Comment: See https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xvii-deployment-on-linux#commentform

Answer (score 0):

You definitely can install supervisor that will allow you to run wathever programa and keep checking the state of it to be sure the program is running.

```
[program:test]
autostart = true
stopsignal=QUIT
user=root
command=uwsgi --master --workers  5 --disable-logging --socket 127.0.0.1:8888
--module web --callable app
priority=1
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile = /data/log
```

To setup supervisor you can take a look of this documentation: https://www.programmersought.com/article/97941378800/ and to start supervisor at boot you can type the following command:

```
# Make sure Supervisor comes up after a reboot.
sudo systemctl enable supervisor

# Bring Supervisor up right now.
sudo systemctl start supervisor
```

To get more information you can go to the next thread: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/281774/ubuntu-server-16-04-cannot-get-supervisor-to-start-automatically.

I'm not an expert with UWSGI but I have seem lot of repositories working with Django and UWSGI using this combination.

Comment: Is there any other option? Can't i use uwsgi for this process?

Comment: Yes, there are other options like `gnicorn` that play the same role. But of course you can use `uwsgi` too.